# Error Code: 1415. Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger

Tags: mysql

I am getting this error

> Error Code: 1415. Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger

when I am trying to execute this code below:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS after_payment_insert//
CREATE TRIGGER after_payment_insert
AFTER INSERT
ON Payment FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET @p = (Select ProductCode from Product Where ProductName = New.ItemName Limit 1);
    Call insertInvoice(New.Email,New.InvoiceNumber, @p, New.ItemName, '1', New.Total, New.Status);
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Also tried this one:

```
DECLARE var_productcode varchar(10);
Select ProductCode into var_productcode from Product Where ProductName = New.ItemName Limit 1;
Call insertInvoice(New.Email,New.InvoiceNumber, var_productcode, New.ItemName, '1', New.Total, New.Status);
```

Both of the code above result to error code 1415.

The insertInvoice is just a simple stored procudure for inserting data from the invoice table.

Below is the InsertInvoice proc

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS insertInvoice//
CREATE PROCEDURE insertInvoice(
    IN insert_Email VARCHAR(255), 
    IN insert_InvoiceNumber VARCHAR(10), 
    IN insert_ProductCode VARCHAR(50), 
    IN insert_ItemName VARCHAR(10), 
    IN insert_Quantity VARCHAR(10), 
    IN insert_Price VARCHAR(10), 
    IN insert_Status VARCHAR(50))
    
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Invoice(Email, InvoiceNumber, ProductCode, ItemName, Quantity, Price, Status)
VALUES(insert_Email, insert_InvoiceNumber,insert_ProductCode, insert_ItemName, insert_Quantity, insert_Price, insert_Status);
END
//DELIMITER ;
```

But when I use the normal Insert Into (....) Values(...) it just works.

Comment: Do you mind also posting the create tables, i would like to test this, also which mysql are you using 8.0.x?

Comment: i tried your  your by building my oqn dbfiddle and can't reproduce it https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=1676540f16cbe219feac68316af29ec6  see if you cqan change it that it produces an error

Comment: Use single INSERT .. SELECT. Both SP and variable not needed.